# WrapPanel doesn't work as a ItemsPanelTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wrappanel

I've an `ItemsControl` with the following code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeModelList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:SomeUserControl ModelValue="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But visually, I've only one column of items, and some items are not displayed(overflow on the bottom of the windows). What should I do to get those in two column when not space available?

**Edit**

in fact, if I set a "MaxWidth", I get two column, but this is still not working as expected, because if I've not a lot of items, they should be on one column and use the available space

**Edit 2**

Some more informations:
My container(the one with the ItemsControl) is a window, that contains a Grid. One of the cell is allocated to this ItemsControl. It is set to use all the remaining space.

The userControl are composed with one DockPanel, which contains some textBlock and a graphic. Even if there is no Height specified, this control cannot grow in height, but in width.

Comment: Have you tried setting a MaxHeight / VerticalAlignment, so the WrapPanel knows when it should wrap?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Actually not, because the day I add 1 control within my UserControl, I don't want to have to look all the usages to find where its value has been fixed(I just tested it, it doesn't seems to help if I add a `MaxHeight` on the SomeUserControl usage

Comment: No I meant on the WrapPanel in the ItemsPanelTemplate, just to test if it's just a layouting problem. If it wraps when a MaxHeight is set and the VerticalScrollBar is disabled, it would be a completely different problem as when it doesn't.

Comment: I have tried your code and for me works. I just have set the height of the item control. Obviously it depends from your layout.

Comment: Just put the ItemsControl in a Panel that sets its size, e.g. a Grid. A Canvas won't do.

Comment: How is the user control defined? Does it define any height. I think the problem is the wrap panel gets undefined height when layouting its items so it cannot split it into columns.

Comment: @cicciorocca I cannot set a fixed size, since the goal is to adapt to the size of the window.

Comment: @Clemens It's within a Grid, but the cell has `*` sizes(since it should take sthe available size

Comment: @michauzo The usercontrol is one DockPanel, and within it, 2 others controls. There is no explicit size set.

Comment: I supposed it...However it should work.

Comment: @cicciorocca in fact the issue is that every item is capable of using the full width available, so the WrapPanel doesn't wrap since it thinks there is not enough space

Comment: AFAIK WrapPanel with vertical orientation will eventually overflow horizontally. It can only overflow vertically if height of single item is bigger then the height of the Panel. I don't think the issue is items' width, I rather think it's related to items' height. Is it possible to extract a code example that will allow us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @michauzo While trying to create a sample, i did notice something: Within my UserControl, I've a DevExpress chart(which has a fixed height, but can use as much width as he is provided). If I replace it with something else, I don't have the issue anymore